# SOLR error java.lang.ClassCastException during indexing DenseVectorField

Tags: indexing, solr, vectorization

I'm trying to index vector of dimension 1536 into solr, this is my config.

fieldType

```
{
  "add-field-type": {
    "name": "vec1536",
    "class": "solr.DenseVectorField",
    "vectorDimension": "1536",
    "similarityFunction": "cosine"
  }
}
```

field

```
<field name="vectorized" type="vec1536" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

when i'm trying to index, i noticed for some numbers its giving clasCastException, I narrowed down to the number thats causing the issue and replaced the rest with `1` for better readability

```
curl --location 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/new_core/update/json?commitWithin=5000&wt=json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '[
    {
        "id": "0bwGslsBWZVEFdPLVIet",
        "vectorized": [
            1,
            -0.0000035723198834602954,
            ...1534 1s
           ]
    }
]'
```

when i try to index i get below error

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 500,
        "QTime": 15
    },
    "error": {
        "metadata": [
            "error-class",
            "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
            "root-error-class",
            "java.lang.ClassCastException"
        ],
        "msg": "ERROR: [doc=0bwGslsBWZVEFdPLVIet] Error adding field 'vectorized'='[1, -0.0000035723198834602954, ...rest of 1s]' msg=Error while creating field 'vectorized{type=vec1536,properties=indexed,stored,omitNorms,omitTermFreqAndPositions,useDocValuesAsStored,uninvertible}' from value '[1, -0.0000035723198834602954, ...rest of 1s]'",
        "trace": "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=0bwGslsBWZVEFdPLVIet] Error adding field 'vectorized'='[1, -0.0000035723198834602954, ...rest of 1s]' msg=Error while creating field 'vectorized{type=vec1536,properties=indexed,stored,omitNorms,omitTermFreqAndPositions,useDocValuesAsStored,uninvertible}' from value '[1, -0.0000035723198834602954,...rest of 1s]'\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:248)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:100)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand.lambda$makeLuceneDocs$0(AddUpdateCommand.java:233)\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.lambda$initPartialTraversalState$0(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$AbstractWrappingSpliterator.fillBuffer(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$AbstractWrappingSpliterator.doAdvance(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.util.Spliterators$1Adapter.hasNext(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocuments(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:233)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocuments(DocumentsWriter.java:432)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocuments(IndexWriter.java:1545)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocuments(IndexWriter.java:1521)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.updateDocOrDocValues(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:1062)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.doNormalUpdate(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:421)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:374)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:311)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessorFactory$RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:76)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.NestedUpdateProcessorFactory$NestedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(NestedUpdateProcessorFactory.java:79)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:268)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doVersionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:544)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.lambda$versionAdd$0(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:356)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.VersionBucket.runWithLock(VersionBucket.java:51)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:353)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:234)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory$LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:111)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory$AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.java:535)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:111)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:111)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:111)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:111)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory$1.processAdd(FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory.java:71)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:111)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory$DefaultValueUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory.java:82)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.handleAdds(JsonLoader.java:553)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.processUpdate(JsonLoader.java:183)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:151)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:86)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:102)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:84)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:224)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2893)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.executeCoreRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:871)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:567)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.dispatch(SolrDispatchFilter.java:250)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(SolrDispatchFilter.java:218)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.ServletUtils.traceHttpRequestExecution2(ServletUtils.java:257)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.ServletUtils.rateLimitRequest(ServletUtils.java:227)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:213)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:195)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:210)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:527)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:223)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1570)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:221)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1384)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:176)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:484)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1543)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:174)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1306)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:149)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:228)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:141)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:301)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:822)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:563)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$0(HttpChannel.java:505)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:762)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:497)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:282)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:314)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:969)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1194)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1149)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\nCaused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error while creating field 'vectorized{type=vec1536,properties=indexed,stored,omitNorms,omitTermFreqAndPositions,useDocValuesAsStored,uninvertible}' from value '[1, -0.0000035723198834602954, ...rest of 1s]'\n\tat org.apache.solr.schema.DenseVectorField.createFields(DenseVectorField.java:246)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.addField(DocumentBuilder.java:67)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.addOriginalField(DocumentBuilder.java:304)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:193)\n\t... 96 more\nCaused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number (java.lang.String and java.lang.Number are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')\n\tat org.apache.solr.util.vector.DenseVectorParser.parseIndexVector(DenseVectorParser.java:72)\n\tat org.apache.solr.util.vector.DenseVectorParser.parseVector(DenseVectorParser.java:45)\n\tat org.apache.solr.util.vector.FloatDenseVectorParser.getFloatVector(FloatDenseVectorParser.java:34)\n\tat org.apache.solr.schema.DenseVectorField.createField(DenseVectorField.java:265)\n\tat org.apache.solr.schema.DenseVectorField.createFields(DenseVectorField.java:229)\n\t... 99 more\n",
        "code": 500
    }
}
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=0bwGslsBWZVEFdPLVIet] Error adding field 'vectorized'='[1, -0.0000035723198834602954, ...rest of 1s]' msg=Error while creating field 'vectorized{type=vec1536,properties=indexed,stored,omitNorms,omitTermFreqAndPositions,useDocValuesAsStored,uninvertible}' from value '[1, -0.0000035723198834602954,...rest of 1s]'
    at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:248)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:100)
    at org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand.lambda$makeLuceneDocs$0(AddUpdateCommand.java:233)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.lambda$initPartialTraversalState$0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$AbstractWrappingSpliterator.fillBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$AbstractWrappingSpliterator.doAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$1Adapter.hasNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocuments(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:233)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocuments(DocumentsWriter.java:432)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocuments(IndexWriter.java:1545)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocuments(IndexWriter.java:1521)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.updateDocOrDocValues(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:1062)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.doNormalUpdate(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:421)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:374)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:311)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessorFactory$RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:76)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.NestedUpdateProcessorFactory$NestedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(NestedUpdateProcessorFactory.java:79)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:268)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doVersionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:544)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.lambda$versionAdd$0(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:356)
    at org.apache.solr.update.VersionBucket.runWithLock(VersionBucket.java:51)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:353)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:234)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory$LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:111)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory$AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.java:535)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:111)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:111)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:111)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:111)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory$1.processAdd(FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory.java:71)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:111)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:54)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory$DefaultValueUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory.java:82)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.handleAdds(JsonLoader.java:553)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.processUpdate(JsonLoader.java:183)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:151)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:86)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:84)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:224)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2893)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.executeCoreRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:871)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:567)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.dispatch(SolrDispatchFilter.java:250)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(SolrDispatchFilter.java:218)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.ServletUtils.traceHttpRequestExecution2(ServletUtils.java:257)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.ServletUtils.rateLimitRequest(ServletUtils.java:227)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:213)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1570)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1543)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1306)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:822)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$0(HttpChannel.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:969)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1194)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1149)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error while creating field 'vectorized{type=vec1536,properties=indexed,stored,omitNorms,omitTermFreqAndPositions,useDocValuesAsStored,uninvertible}' from value '[1, -0.0000035723198834602954, ...rest of 1s]'
    at org.apache.solr.schema.DenseVectorField.createFields(DenseVectorField.java:246)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.addField(DocumentBuilder.java:67)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.addOriginalField(DocumentBuilder.java:304)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:193)
    ... 96 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number (java.lang.String and java.lang.Number are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.apache.solr.util.vector.DenseVectorParser.parseIndexVector(DenseVectorParser.java:72)
    at org.apache.solr.util.vector.DenseVectorParser.parseVector(DenseVectorParser.java:45)
    at org.apache.solr.util.vector.FloatDenseVectorParser.getFloatVector(FloatDenseVectorParser.java:34)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.DenseVectorField.createField(DenseVectorField.java:265)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.DenseVectorField.createFields(DenseVectorField.java:229)
    ... 99 more
",


Stack trace made readable by https://TidyTrace.com
```

the weird part is, if i add number `-0.0000035723198834602954` at index 0, solr accepts the request. What am i missing?